# postgres case ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: database, postgresql, switch-statement

```
with temp as(
select a.fk_audit_inserimento
from mtd.t_mtd_all_dt_elab_etl a,mtd.t_mtd_all_dt_anag_etl b
where a.fk_etl_caricamento=b.pk_etl_caricamento
and b.sds_livello='DMT' and b.sds_nome_etl='JOB_DM_MOBILE_CODE'
order by 1 desc
limit 2
)

select
case 
when
(select count(*) from temp)=1
then
(select 19000101000000, 
union
select fk_audit_inserimento from temp)
when
(select count(*) from temp)=2
then (select fk_audit_inserimento from temp)
end
```

I want that 
`If count (*) of TEMP =1` then I want two records `19000101000000` and the `select fk_audit_inserimento from temp;`
`If count(*) of TEMP =2` then I want `select fk_audit_inserimento from temp.`

But I have

> ERROR: multiple rows.

How i can resolve it??

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
SELECT 19000101000000
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM temp)=1
UNION
SELECT fk_audit_inserimento FROM temp ;
```